# How to save data from textbox to dartagridview

Tags: c#, visual-studio

https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?fbid=494142207337085&set=a.102999783117998.6074.100002239302471&type=1&theater

Our goal is to send the data from serial port to textbox as well as in the data grid view. How are we supposed to that? Any comments or suggestions will be appreciated. By the way we are using c# visual studio 2012.

```
      string RxString;

      public Form1()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void buttonStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          serialPort1.PortName = "COM71";
          serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;

          serialPort1.Open();
          if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
          {
              buttonStart.Enabled = false;
              buttonStop.Enabled = true;
              dataGridView1.Rows.Add(10);
          }
      }

      private void buttonStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if (serialPort1.IsOpen)
          {
              serialPort1.Close();
              buttonStart.Enabled = true;
              buttonStop.Enabled = false;

          }

      }

      private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
      {
          if (serialPort1.IsOpen) serialPort1.Close();
      }

      private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
      {

          if (!serialPort1.IsOpen) return;

          char[] buff = new char[1];

          buff[0] = e.KeyChar;


          serialPort1.Write(buff, 0, 1);


      }



      private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          textBox1.AppendText(RxString);


      }

      private void serialPort1_DataReceived
        (object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
      {
          RxString = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
          this.Invoke(new EventHandler(DisplayText));
          dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0].Value = textBox1.Lines[0];

      }




  }
```

}

i dont know how to transfer the data from text to each row in the datagridview. please help :'(

@codeswithhammer

ive used this these codes but still didnt work it says that method must have return type

```
    private DataTable myTable = new DataTable();



    public Form2()

    {

        InitializeComponent();

        // initialise

        this.initialiseTable(this.myTable);
        // set source

        this.dataGridView1.DataSource = this.myTable;

    }

    /// <summary>

    /// Initialise a table

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="table">The table to initialise</param>

    private void initialiseTable(DataTable table)

    {

        // add all columns

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column1"));

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column2"));

        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Column3"));

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

    {

        // create a row
        DataRow rd = this.myTable.NewRow();
       // set values

        rd[0] = textBox1.Text;

        rd[1] = textBox2.Text;

        rd[2] = textBox3.Text;
        // add row to table
        this.myTable.Rows.Add(rd);
    }


    }
}
```

i've only have what the picture file above shows

Comment: Your application is now writing data from the textbox to the serialport, so it's outputting data, but I tought you would like to get input from a source and put the data in a textbox?

Comment: @MaxMommersteeg i want the data shown in the textbow to be in the gridview. i ve already make it to have data in textbox

Answer (score 0):

assume your datagridview is unbound with 3 column.

assume your text in txtBox1 is separated by ','

so

```
 string[] txt = textBox1.Text.Split(',');
 dataGridView1.Rows.Add(txt[0], txt[1], txt[2]);
```

hope this do help

```
  private void DisplayText(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      textBox1.AppendText(RxString);
      DataGridView1.Rows.Add(RxString); //consider 1 row has only 1 column
  }
```

Comment: it doesnt help. We need to hava datagridview which rows are updated when there is a data stored in textbox.

Comment: if you want to edit a cell --> dataGridView1.Rows[r].Cells[c].Value = new_value

Comment: when data from textbox is store to datagridview it only writes in one cell our goal is to display from multiline of textbox, and each line will be displayed also in a datagridview in each rows,

Comment: it is like putting line 1 - datagridview[0,1]
line 2 - datagridview[0,2]

Comment: if understand you correctly...as my original answer,you need to use >>> DataGridView1.Rows.Add()